# Angular2 calling a service from another service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have 2 services - 1/Files and 2/FTPClient in angular2.

They are Singleton services - and work perfectly when injected into a component through its constructor like this :

```
constructor(public filesIn:Files, public ftpIn:FTPClient){}
```

SO now I would like to use the Files server within the FTPClient itself...so I try the same thing. This is my code for the constructor of the FTPClient service:

```
constructor(public filesIn:Files) {
        this.files = filesIn;
    }
```

But this throws the error:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for FTPClient (?)
```

My application only has one module - and both the Files and FTPClient are in the providers list :

```
 providers: [APIData,FTPClient,Files,SSHClient, WINDOW_PROVIDER]
```

Please can you shed some light on what I am doing wrong here!

Comment: Do you have `@Injectable()` decorator on top of your `FTPClient` class?

Comment: No - when I add that (I did try!) it throws  error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Injectable'.

Comment: well then import 'Injectable' in your service.

Comment: well then 'how'! That bit is not in the docs

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class yourService {
  //service code here
}

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injectable doc here

Comment: Harry - note that doesn't mention anywhere the import Injectable bit...which is where i fell down.

Answer (score -1):

I had to add the `@Injectable()` decorator just above my class began - and import Injectable into the file by including the line :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
```